# Cloze items inside code block in org-drill

Tags: org-mode, org-drill

The title pretty much speaks for itself. Using the usual cloze syntax, e.g.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC haskell
absurd :: Void -> [a]
#+END_SRC
```

Does not work, as `[a]` is visible during the drill session.

Comment: Org mode does not "see" inside code blocks: syntactically, they are a black box. The only thing it does is to pass the string to the appropriate babel evaluation function as determined by the language specified in the block.

Comment: @NickD That's unfurtunate... so is there no hope for syntax highlighted clozes in org-drill?

Comment: Not sure what that means: all I'm prepared to say is that Org mode will provide no help in recognizing *anything* inside a source block. All it knows how to do is pass the string as a whole to babel for evaluation (and do syntax highlighting on it by asking the appropriate mode to do that, but I'm not clear on the details of that, so this may well be wrong).